# How can I use ->where() in this Laravel query?

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-10

I want to use ->where('sold', 0). So it only selects the listings from a certain product which are not sold yet. (sold = 0 => not sold, sold = 1 => sold).

```
    public function showProducts()
    {
        $products = Product::leftJoin('listings', 'products.id', '=', 'listings.pid')
            ->groupBy('products.id', 'products.name', 'products.first_image', 'products.stylecode', 'products.brand', 'products.release_date', 'products.sold', 'products.slug')
            ->select('products.*', DB::raw('MIN(listings.price) as min_price'))
            ->get();

        return view('index', compact('products'));
    }
```

Tried ->where('sold', 0) but it's a combined query. I could not find a solution.

Comment: `->where('listings.sold', 0)`? Or, define a relationship between the 2, then do `Product::whereHas('listings', function ($subQuery) { return $subQuery->where('sold', 0); })->get()`. Docs for reference: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships and https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Comment: Thanks, I have added:


`->where('listings.sold', 0)
->orwhere('listings.sold', NULL)`

Otherwise I wouldn't show the products without any listings.

Comment: Yup, that'll work. Sidenote though, you might want to do `->where(function ($subQuery) { return $subQuery->where('listings.sold', 0)->orWhereNull('listings.sold'); })`, which generates the SQL `(WHERE listings.sold = 0 OR listings.sold IS NULL)` (notice the `()` around that), to better scope your query and prevent any unexpected results should you add another `where()` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can use eager loading to preload the related listings for each product to avoid the [N+1 query problem](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

```
public function showProducts()
{
    $products = Product::with(['listings' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('sold', 0);
    }])
    // ->select('products.*', DB::raw('MIN(listings.price) as min_price'))
    ->selectSub(function ($query) {
        $query->selectRaw('MIN(price)')
            ->from('listings')
            ->whereColumn('listings.pid', 'products.id');
    }, 'min_price')
    ->groupBy('products.id')
    ->get();

    return view('index', compact('products'));
}
```

By using eager loading with a subquery to filter the listings that are not sold yet, you can eliminate the need to use a join or group by clause, making the query faster.

Also, consider adding an `index` on the `listings.sold` column to speed up the `where` condition.

```
ALTER TABLE listings ADD INDEX sold_index (sold);
```

Comment: Tested this, but now I have the issue that it is looking for "listings.price" in the products table.

`SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'listings.price' in 'field list' (Connection: mysql, SQL: select 'products'*, MIN(listings.price) as min_price from 'products' group by 'products'.'id')`

Comment: Hello @Kai, I replaced it with `selectSub` method. Perhaps this will solve the problem.